# How to migrate Spring Boot project to legacy Spring MVC project. Facing problem, how to read application.properties file in legacy Spring MVC project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, openid-connect, spring-oauth2

I have done the POC in Spring Boot application. But our project is running on legacy Spring MVC.

The problem I am facing while converting Spring Boot project to Spring MVC, to read  application.properties file.

The content of the Spring Boot application.properties file is as below

```
okta.oauth2.issuer=https://dev-3038103.okta.com/oauth2/bus3zhc6ayn7hfzQN5d6
resourceServer.url=http://localhost:8082
okta.oauth2.clientId={client-id}
okta.oauth2.clientSecret={secret-id}
okta.oauth2.scopes=openid,profile
server.port=8080
```

Can anyone please tell me how to handle?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this,

- Using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
- Using PropertySource
- Using ResourceBundleMessageSource
- Using PropertiesFactoryBean

this is like a go to source.

Register PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean-

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:path/filename.properties"/>
```

i am providing the implementation with first method however you can very easily about the rest, follow any one